# Progress OpenEdge like SQL where IN?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I can do this with a string and it works great.
example:

```
for each emp no-lock where
   lookup(emp.name, "james,john,kerry,david") <> 0:
  /* Do something */
end.
```

Now I have emp.ID that is not a string (it's an integer) how can I do where IN ? I tried similar method as above. but it gives me an error, it says
"incompatible data types"

```
for each emp no-lock where
    lookup(emp.ID, "1,5,89") :
  /* Do something */
end.
```

how do I do this ?
thank yo u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a large DB table, to make good use of indexes:

```
FOR EACH emp NO-LOCK WHERE emp.ID = 1 OR emp.ID = 5 OR emp.ID ? 89
```

A lazy coder in a small table might do:

```
FOR EACH emp NO-LOCK WHERE LOOKUP (STRING(emp.ID), "1,5,89") > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

OpenEdge has a SQL-92 engine but you aren't using that.  You are using the 4gl engine.  There is some limited SQL-89 syntax  embedded inside the 4gl engine but it is a bad idea to try to use it.  It only leads to pain and suffering

The 4gl has no IN function.  To do what you are trying to do with a variable set of integers you would probably want to first create a temp-table and then join the TT with your real table.  Something like this:

```
define temp-table tt_intList
  field f1 as integer
.

create tt_intList.
tt_intList.f1 = 1.

create tt_intList.
tt_intList.f1 = 5.

create tt_intList.
tt_intList.f1 = 89.

for each tt_intList, each emp no-lock where emp.Id = tt_intList.f1:
  display emp.Id emp.name.
end.
```

Comment: I have version 11.3.3 does that has SQL-92 engine?

Comment: Yes.  But you are using FOR EACH so you are coding with the 4GL engine.  Application code almost always uses the 4GL.  The SQL-92 engine is primarily used for 3rd party interfaces and reporting purposes.